# notifyDataSetChanged() fails to update adapter onClick

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) on ExpandableListViews. I want my implementation to show a new value added after tapping a button. However, nothing I have tried works. In addition to playing around with notifyDataSetChanged(), I also tried notifyDataSetInvalidated() and instantiating a new adapter, which were suggested in similar posts. The new data that isn't showing up is under my onClick method.

Any suggestions on a fix?

```
public class ClassesFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
private View v;

 Integer term;
 String termSelection;

 ListView myList;
 EditText editText1;
 Spinner spinner;

 MyExpandableListAdapter adapter;
 ExpandableListView listView;

 SparseArray<Group> groups = new SparseArray<Group>();

 Group fall2013 = new Group("Fall 2013");
 Group winter2014 = new Group("Winter 2014");
 Group spring2014 = new Group("Spring 2014");
 Group summer2014 = new Group("Summer 2014");


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_classes, container, false);

    editText1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerItemSelectedListener());



    Button add = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

    createData();
    listView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), groups);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;              
}

public void createData() {      
    groups.append(0, fall2013);
    groups.append(1, winter2014);
    groups.append(2, spring2014);
    groups.append(3, summer2014);

}

@SuppressWarnings("boxing")
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {           
        case R.id.button1:                  

            Integer crn = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
            editText1.setText("");

            if (termSelection.toString() == "Fall 2013") {                      

                fall2013.children.add(crn.toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            break;

            case R.id.button2:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on delete button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;  

        }
   }


   public class SpinnerItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            termSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        }
    }
}
```

My custom adapter:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

  private final SparseArray<Group> groups;
  public LayoutInflater inflater;
  public Activity activity;

  public MyExpandableListAdapter(Activity act, SparseArray<Group> groups) {
    activity = act;
    this.groups = groups;
    inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
      boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(children);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, children,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
    return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).children.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
  }

  @Override
  public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
      View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_group, null);
    }
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(group.string);
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
    return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method doesn't work for me also (and I'm not sure why. My guess is that it will only work with Contnet providers). Instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` you can just requery/add new data to your `groups` and reset the `adapter`.

```
adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), groups);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: …and this is very inefficient… you're creating a new adapter every time.

Answer (score 1):

your if statement is probably never called:

```
 if (termSelection.toString() == "Fall 2013")
```

should be

```
 if (termSelection.toString().equals("Fall 2013"))
```

EDIT:

== checks for object identity, when using Strings. you most probably mean equals instead.

Also i'd advise you to get familiar with the debugger and/or LogCat/Log.d(), this will save you tons of trouble;

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine, so I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting list adapter again:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding your notifysetchange with runOnUIThread(new Runnable(...)). Since you make a change with your listView it should be updated within your UI thread. Also a good way if you are not familiar with the breakpoints, try logging with your if statements and see if your conditions are set true.

Comment: `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
      });`